# How to return null when list is empty in Java 8?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, option-type

How can I change this method so that it returns `null` if the list passed as a parameter is *empty* without using an `if` statement?

```
 default String getFiltersExpression(List<WorklistViewDto.Filter> filters) {
    return Optional.ofNullable(filters)
        .map(Collection::stream)
        .orElseGet(Stream::empty)
        .map(WorkListViewMapper::formatValue)
        .map(f -> f.getCriteria() + f.getOperator() + f.getValue())
        .collect(Collectors.joining(" AND ", "(", ")"));
}
```

Comment: `return Optional...orElse(null);` (`List` is not an *array*)

Comment: There are no arrays here. You mean the list?

Comment: yes the list sorry.

Comment: the problem here is if i put orElse(null) or .orElseGet(Stream::empty) or orElseGet(null). the methode returns a string = "()"

Comment: What about a good old `if` statement?

Comment: Why return null, not optional? Returning null is always the first step towards a NPE.

Comment: Actually, if there are no filters( even when its `null`) what's the harm in returning `"()"`?

Comment: this value is passed to a distant WS which does not accept this value i need it to be null if list is empty

Comment: can anyone help me to fix this code without using if

Comment: Are you building an sql statement?

Comment: Why want to return `null` in the first place? An empty list is safer and just as useful in almost all cases.

Answer (score 6):

You can do it with [Collectors.collectingAndThen](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#collectingAndThen-java.util.stream.Collector-java.util.function.Function-) .

```
.collect( 
    Collectors.collectingAndThen(
        Collectors.joining(), 
        str->{
            if(str.isEmpty()) return null; 
            return str;
        }
     )
 );
```

Given OP's joining statement, `Collectors.joining(" AND ", "(", ")")` we could modify the above.

```
Collectors.collectingAndThen(
    Collectors.joining(" AND "), 
    str->{
            if(str.isEmpty()) return null; 
            return "(" + str + ")";
    })
```

Comment: I suspect the problem here would be that the `str` would not be empty anymore after the `joining` operation as in the question. It shall just be returning `"()"` to what I [can guess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54766588/how-to-return-null-when-list-is-empty-in-java-8/54766660#comment96313706_54766588).

Comment: @nullpointer Ill edit it, my point was more to use another collector.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend not returning null and rather returning a `"()"` string as the filter expression for this you can just append a filter for an empty list there as :

```
String getFiltersExpression(List<Filter> filters) {
    return Optional.ofNullable(filters)
            .filter(l -> !l.isEmpty())
            .map(Collection::stream)
            .orElseGet(Stream::empty)
            .map(WorkListViewMapper::formatValue)
            .map(f -> f.getCriteria() + f.getOperator())
            .collect(Collectors.joining(" AND ", "(", ")"));
}
```

Using Java-9 syntax :

```
String getFiltersExpressions(List<Filter> filters) {
    return Stream.ofNullable(filters)
            .flatMap(Collection::stream)
            .map(WorkListViewMapper::formatValue)
            .map(f -> f.getCriteria() + f.getOperator() + f.getValue())
            .collect(Collectors.joining(" AND ", "(", ")"));
}
```

Comment: The OP wants to return `null` when the list is empty, not treat a `null` input like an empty list. Besides that, the `.filter(l -> !l.isEmpty())` step of the first variant is obsolete.

Comment: @Holger Agreed. This is a recommendation more than the desired output. Yes, I was thinking of that, if the `Collection::stream` should suffice to create `Stream.empty` in the first variant in which case OP's actual code would be doing the same operation.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative way is to start streaming only if the list is non null and non empty:

```
default String getFiltersExpression(List<WorklistViewDto.Filter> filters) {
    return Optional.ofNullable(filters)
            .filter(fs -> !fs.isEmpty())
            .map(fs -> fs.stream()
                    .map(WorkListViewMapper::formatValue)
                    .map(f -> f.getCriteria() + f.getOperator() + f.getValue())
                    .collect(Collectors.joining(" AND ", "(", ")")))
            .orElse(null);
}
```

Then you get null instead of `()`.

Comment: …another case of “how to make my code more complicated by inserting `Optional`. Compare with `return filters == null || filters.isEmpty()? null: fs.stream() 
 .map(WorkListViewMapper::formatValue)  .map(f -> f.getCriteria() + f.getOperator() + f.getValue())  .collect(Collectors.joining(" AND ", "(", ")"));`

Comment: @Holger according to the code in question wouldn't the output for `filters == null` be `()`? I initially thought of this, but then that's the reason I think the question is a bit complicated.

Comment: @nullpointer it’s not clear which behavior the OP intends. The code example is designed to treat `null` and empty list the same, but the question only asks for a particular behavior for the empty list. You can interpret it one way or the other. But my previous comment was just addressing the code of this answer, showing how to achieve the same simpler without an `Optional`.